# Git reversing mistake

Tags: git

Recently, one of the contributors to our project made a commit which broke our system. I am trying to revert back to the latest working release:

I use git log to find the commit:

```
commit 45359d69e7983946b233d9010f205be19ce8ebfe
Author:Tom
Date:   Mon Apr 14 14:59:50 2014 +0100

    Tweaks the interface to make it more clean
```

I then do:

```
git checkout 45359d69e7983946b233d9010f205be19ce8ebfe
```

Followed by:

```
git add -A && git commit -am "revert"
```

And I finally try:

```
git push
```

Which returns:

```
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'path'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.  See the
'Note about fast-forwards' section of 'git push --help' for details.
```

(Where it says path I just removed the url of the server)

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To revert a commit with git, use `git revert $commit`. It will create new commit with the reverse changes (so you will be back at the original version without the changes).